# Angular 2 and TypeScript Promise return array

Tags: angular, typescript, es6-promise

I am trying to return an array from a service using Promise.Then. The function is my service is follow:

```
userList: Users[] = [];

getUsers = {
    userList: (): Promise<Users[]> => {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.authenticationService.token);
        return this.http.get(this.authenticationService.url + '/tournament/getGames', {
            headers: headers
        }).map((response: Response) => {
            var status = response.json().status;
            console.log(response.json().status);
            if (status) {                   
                this.userList = response.json().users;
                console.info(response.json().users);
                return this.userList;
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }).toPromise();

    }
}
```

then I am using this in administrator.component.ts to get the Users list:

```
usersList: Users[] = [];
```

inside ngOnInit:

```
this.getData().then(() => this.isDataAvailable = true);
```

getData function:

```
 getData(): Promise<Users[]> {
    return this.UserService.getUsers().then(users => {
        this.usersList= users;
        console.log(this.usersList);
    });
}
```

and the code is returning this error message:

*cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature*

Any help is much appreciated as I use a similar logic in a different component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your service `getUsers` is not a function. `getUsers.userList` is the function. So you should call it with `this.UserService.getUsers.userList()`.